# Measuring Techum to include the city's Eruv

Tags: eruv-chatzerot, techum

(Note: the halachot of measuring Techum in practice are very complex, and an expert should be consulted.)

In general terms, the start of a Techum measurement is the dwelling which is designated as the center. If this dwelling is inside a courtyard, measurement instead starts from the courtyard edges.

Since an Eruv established for the purpose of allowing carrying inside the community on Shabbat is effectively a courtyard around all of the houses, does this mean that the measurement of the Techum should start from the edges of the Eruv?

Comment: If the dwelling is in a city even without an eruv the measurement starts from the edge of the city. are you asking about a carrying-eruv that extends far outside the city?

Comment: @DoubleAA There are two possible cases: one is yours in which the Eruv extends far outside the city (because that's where there were convenient poles to use), and the other (the one I was thinking of when I asked the question) is for a semi-rural (or "low density suburban") community.